# clearInterval fails in one scenario but not the other

Tags: jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm running a function to check if a database entry exists.

On my page load I check if an element exists and if it does I use `setInterval` to run a function. Like so:

```
if ( $('#encoding').length ) {

    console.log("auto_update start");
    var update = setInterval(auto_update, 12000);
}
```

Then in my `auto_update` function this happens

```
function auto_update() {

    console.log("auto_update running");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action: "dhf_ajax_router",
            perform: "dhf_check_status", // the function we want to call
            post_id: $('#post_id').val(),
            nonce: $('#dhf-video-meta-nonce').val()
        },
        success: function(response) {

            if ( response === "continue" ) {

                console.log("still encoding");

            } else {

                clearInterval(update);
                console.log("complete " + response);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is if `$('#encoding')` wasn't present on the page at the start and was fired by the user manually within:

```
$(document).on("click", ".run_encode", function(){

        // doing the necessary stuff here.
        if ( response === "sent" ) {

                // more stuff
                var update = setInterval(auto_update, 12000);
        } 

}); // end .run_encode
```

Then the `clearInterval(update)` doesn't work, and it ends up in an endless loop.

I can't figure out Why. An interval with the name `update` was set in both cases, so why does clearing it not work in the second situation?

Comment: Keywords: "javascript variable scoping"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to make sure that the shared variable `update` is available in both scopes.  This means that it either needs to be in a common parent scope or you need to make the `update` variable a global variable so it does not go out of scope.

Most likely, you're declaration of `update` is inside a function that terminates and when that function terminates, the `update` variable goes out of scope and is destroyed.

You can make the initial setting of the variable go into the global scope (so it will still be available when you call `clearInterval()` like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".run_encode", function(){

    // doing the necessary stuff here.
    if ( response === "sent" ) {

            // more stuff
            window.update = setInterval(auto_update, 12000);
    } 

}); // end .run_encode
```

Or, you could just declare the `update` variable to be global, by first putting this at the global level (outside of any functions) and then this code would just modify the global variable:

```
var update;

$(document).on("click", ".run_encode", function(){

        // doing the necessary stuff here.
        if ( response === "sent" ) {

                // more stuff
                update = setInterval(auto_update, 12000);
        } 

}); // end .run_encode
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I used the second example. Just one question, is this an efficient way of doing things or would I better off having some kind of router function that called everything in succession?

Comment: @deadlyhifi - it is not efficient to "poll" your server on an interval until it tells you it's done.  You haven't explained what the whole problem is you're actually trying to solve so I don't know how to best recommend a better solution.

Comment: I'm sending a request off to Zencoder to encode a video file. When I send it I set a flag in the DB to say it's encoding. When done Zencoder sends a callback that deletes that flag and fills in other data (like the locations of the encoded files). I'm polling the DB to see if that flag has gone. If it has then I get the new data and place it on the page.

Answer (score 4):

You declare the `update` variable inside a function. The other function can't access it's value.

jfriend00 gave an extensive answer on how to solve it. I'd take another route: use `setTimeout`. This is recommended anyway, because the AJAX call does not take a constant time but varies every time. Imagine it takes over 12 seconds due to network trouble: you'll be screwed.